# Image border mapping hilighted areas

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mapping, imagemapster

Can someone tel me why the area hilight like the **image 1** doesn't work on my **image 2** et **image 3** in the JSFIDDLE bellow ?

Maybe one the second image does't because i added the responsive pluging map area, but on the image 3 i removed the responsive so we can well see the mapping on tables map but not the hilight.

http://jsfiddle.net/218t0dss/1/

**1) for hilighting map areas**

```
$('img').mapster({
    mapKey: 'state',
    fillColor: 'ff0000', //red
    fillOpacity: 0.7
});

// http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/default.aspx?docs.html
```

**2) for responsive image map areas**

```
$('img#plan-table-2').rwdImageMaps();

// http://mattstow.com/experiment/responsive-image-maps/rwd-image-maps.html
```